# Naming strategy informed by externalized configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

*Note: this is a Spring/Hibernate question. I happened to use Kotlin, but Java answers are welcome too.*

JPA entities *have* to have a constant table and catalog name:

**User.kt**:

```yaml
@Entity
@Table(name="users", catalog="auth")
data class User(
        @Id
        val username: String,
        var password: String
)
```

This is bad news for me.

My MySQL database hosts several different instances of the same application stack. As a result: I have a variety of schemata, namespaced by environment:

```sql
SHOW DATABASES;
```

```csv
sandbox_billing
sandbox_auth
staging_billing
staging_auth
preproduction_billing
preproduction_auth
```

Each application context has one data source, which can access two catalogs: `*_billing` (for domain entities), and `*_auth` (for auth information).

My application has a configurable map `com.stackoverflow.persistence.catalog-overrides`, where one can specify the catalog name to use for that particular application instance:

**application.yml**:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: 'jdbc:mysql://mycooldatabase.com:3306'
com.stackoverflow:
  persistence:
    catalog-overrides:
      billing: sandbox_billing
      auth: sandbox_auth
```

This config is populated into a POKO:

**PersistenceProperties.kt**:

```kotlin
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("com.stackoverflow.persistence")
@NoArgConstructor
data class PersistenceProperties(
        var catalogOverrides: Map<String, String>
)
```

The hope is that I could implement a PhysicalNamingStrategy that could rename catalogs, based on the map of overrides specified in my Spring application config:

**PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl.kt**:

```kotlin
@Component
class PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl(
        val persistenceProperties : PersistenceProperties
) : PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl(), Serializable {

    companion object {
        val INSTANCE = PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl()
    }

    override fun toPhysicalCatalogName(name: Identifier?, context: JdbcEnvironment?): Identifier? {
        if (name == null) {
            return null
        }
        val nominalName = name.text
        var parsedName = if(persistenceProperties.catalogOverrides.containsKey(nominalName)) {
            persistenceProperties.catalogOverrides.get(nominalName)
        } else {
            nominalName
        }
        return Identifier(parsedName, name.isQuoted)
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that Hibernate is responsible for constructing the NamingStrategy, so it's difficult to inject Spring properties into it.

i.e. it's not possible for me to use the usual technique:

**application.yml** (hypothetical):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy: com.stackoverflow.config.PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl
```

Because this does not use Spring's dependency injector (thus I cannot get an instance of PersistenceProperties).

I did *try* to use a service locator to acquire the dependency:

**PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl.kt, ApplicationContextProvider.kt** (hypothetical):

```
@Component
class PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl : PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl(), Serializable {

    private val persistenceProperties : PersistenceProperties = ApplicationContextProvider.CONTEXT.getBean(PersistenceProperties::class.java)

    //...

@Component
class ApplicationContextProvider: ApplicationContextAware {
    companion object {
        lateinit var CONTEXT : ApplicationContext private set
    }

    override fun setApplicationContext(applicationContext: ApplicationContext?) {
        CONTEXT = applicationContext!!
    }
}
```

But Hibernate constructs its PhysicalNamingStrategy very early -- before `setApplicationContext()` fires. So I was unable to use service locator to acquire the application context.

So, I need a way to inject the PhysicalNamingStrategy using Spring. I got close:

**HibernateConfig.kt**:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class HibernateConfig(
        val physicalNamingStrategyImpl: PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl
) {
    @Bean
    fun sessionFactory(dataSource: DataSource): SessionFactory {
        val sessionFactoryBuilder = LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource)
        sessionFactoryBuilder
                .setPhysicalNamingStrategy(physicalNamingStrategyImpl)
        return sessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory()
    }
}
```

But this fires too late in the startup process. All my catalogs are handled by the default SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy, before my hibernate SessionFactory bean is constructed.

So: **how does one inject Spring properties into a PhysicalNamingStrategy, *before* any catalogs are handled**?

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4 and Hibernate 5.0.12.

Comment: Oh, [this article](http://sloanseaman.com/wordpress/2012/02/07/dynamic-configuration-of-hibernate-envers/) seems to be confronted with a similar problem.

Comment: [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-dynamic-table-routin) provides a _particularly horrible workaround_.